# Limit entering a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

In my stochastic processes course there is a passage in a proof where we take a limit in a sum, without entering into the details of the particular application, it's something like
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{m=1}^nf(n,m)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(n,m)$$
So the sum becomes a series and at the same time the limit enters the series.

Intuitively I understand this, but my question is: is this always possible? If not, which conditions are known to make this possible?

I'm also wandering, what happens if we consider integrals? Is it always true (providing all of these limits exist) that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow b}\int_{a}^xf(x,y)dy=\int_a^b\left( \lim_{x\rightarrow b}f(x,y)\right)dy$$?

EDIT: I found an example in which it's not true: if in the first equation we take
$$f(n,m)=\log\left(1+\dfrac{m}{n}\right)$$
each term in the sum on the RHS is zero, but the sum on the LHS is an increasing function of $n$. I think my teacher could have overlooked this passage because it's not obvious that you can do this exchange.

Comment: It is not always possible; the result (and its hypotheses) is known as Tannery's theorem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem